# Is it possible to inject a service into apollo-client's middleware?

Tags: angular, apollo-client

Is it possible to inject a service into apollo-client's middleware? There is Apollo module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-angular At the documentation there is an advice how to implement authentication. The communication is done using localStorage.  http://dev.apollodata.com/angular2/auth.html It is not Angular2 way. I need confirmation. I've been for solution for some time.

Comment: I don't think it is recommending communication with localStorage, I think it is just using that to store the token. You can share the authentication info with your service however you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of two options:

Option 1:

1. Have an Auth service that manages login/tokens etc.
2. Inject the Auth service into the service where you construct Apollo.
3. Inside the middleware that adds your token, retrieve the token from the injected Auth service.

Option 2:

Have the service that constructs your Apollo client also manage Auth state. Inject it into the page where you log in to handle authentication and store the token after.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very old, but just in case, the injection is made into deps:

```
    providers: [
        {
          provide: APOLLO_NAMED_OPTIONS,
          deps: [HttpLink, AuthService],
          useFactory: createApollo,
        },
      ],
```

then you just add a parameter into your `createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink, authService: AuthService)` factory function.